# sstreamライブラリーの使いかたを忘れてしまいました。目的は配列の中に入っているint型の値をstring型に直し、さらに数字と数字の間にコンマとスペース1つを入れたいです。

Tags: c++

今回の目的はint型の配列に入っている値を取り出して、それらをコンマと１スペースをそれぞれの数字の値の間に入れてstring型の変数に入れることです。しかし、以下のプログラムでは、outputに入るのは1,　しか入りません。試してみたことは、スペースを除き、それぞれの数字の間にコンマだけを入れてみました。その結果、1,4,7,10,13　がoutputに入りましたが、これは実際にやりたいことではありません。コンマの後ろに一つスペースを入れたいです。これを解決策分かる方いらしたら、よろしくお願います。

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;
const int SIZE = 5;
int main() {
    int array[SIZE] = {1, 4, 7, 10, 13};
    string output;
    stringstream ss;

    for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        ss << array[i] << ", ";
    }
    
    ss >> output;

    cout << "The result should be 1, 4, 7, 10, 13   Not like this: 1,4,7,10,13" << endl;
    cout << "The result is " << output << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`ss >> output`だとスペースの手前までしか取り出せないので、まとめて取り出す`ss.str()`を使いましょう。
あと、このままだと末尾に余計な`,` が追加されてしまうので、少し手を入れています。

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;
const int SIZE = 5;
int main() {
    int array[SIZE] = { 1, 4, 7, 10, 13 };
    string output;
    stringstream ss;

    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        if (i > 0)
            ss << ", ";
        ss << array[i];
    }

    output = ss.str();

    cout << "The result should be 1, 4, 7, 10, 13   Not like this: 1,4,7,10,13" << endl;
    cout << "The result is " << output << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: .str()で取り出せるでとりだせるのでしたか。すっかり忘れてしまっていました。また、先にコンマを置くという方法も学ばせていただきました。こちらのほうがすっきりしていていいですね。ありがとうございます。